# Verification system for vaccination, medicine

Tags: database, internal-transactions, contract-verification, blockchain-as-a-service, off-chain

Project Idea, Need Guidance.

Verification system for vaccination.
Vaccination confirmation per individual, multiple times, different locations.
Can also be used for ticketing, voucher confirmation, medical prescriptions etc.
High amount of transactions, not all could be done in locations with web access, or poor connections. Availability of of-chain transactions is a priority.

Maybe anyone working with similar technical solutions or could connect me with devs in this area of expertise?

Comment: Hi! Reddit, Twitter, or another social platform would be better suited for dev matchmaking - this forum is meant for technical Q&A. Good luck!